# tikz: positioning when using metrics without and with units

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, templates, units

I am having some difficulties with my beamer theme, I think because I am using tikz with positions with and without units.

I want a list that uses the page number `(0,\pgnbr)`, which I defined as having `y=1.5cm` on `\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.5cm]` but then I cannot shift it using unitary metrics. I.e. `(0,\pgnbr+2cm)` seems to distort everything.

It is probably easier to look at what happens. It's pretty obvious what's wrong in my template:

1. I want the titlebar square to expand
2. I want the sidebar to shift down to not overlap the titlebar
3. the sidebar should "stretch"  (see my comment on the line  `\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.5cm]`)

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Ricardo Cruz}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% SIDEBAR

\def\swidth{1.2cm}  % sidebar size
\def\sheight{\paperheigth / \inserttotalframenumber}
\def\theight{1.0cm}  % frametitle size

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=\swidth}
\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1.5cm]   % FIXME: y=\sheight not working !
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\inserttotalframenumber} {
        \def\pgnbr{\inserttotalframenumber - \i-1}
        \ifnum\i=\insertframenumber
            \filldraw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[white,anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \else
            \draw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth-0.07cm,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% TITLE

\setbeamersize{frametitle height=\theight}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\theight);
\node[anchor=mid] at (\paperwidth/2,\theight/2) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{First}
First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
Second
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third}
Third
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

The template I am trying to mimic:

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/cv/adaboost_matas.pdf

Comment: Your code throws the following error for me: `Package keyval Error: frametitle height undefined.`

Comment: And by the way, you've misspelled `\paperheigth` in `\sheight`. Should be `\paperheight`.

Comment: It might be easier, if your define your length variables as `\newlength\theight \setlength\theight{1.0cm}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\let\Tiny=\tiny


\title{Title}
\author{Ricardo Cruz}
\date{}

\usepackage{tikz}

%% SIDEBAR

\newlength\swidth
\setlength\swidth{1.2cm}    

\newlength\theight
\setlength\theight{1.0cm}   

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\makeatother

\newlength\sheight

\setbeamersize{sidebar width right=\swidth}
\setbeamerfont{sidebar right}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
\vspace{\theight}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=\sheight]
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\inserttotalframenumber} {
        \def\pgnbr{\inserttotalframenumber - \i-1}
        \ifnum\i=\insertframenumber
            \filldraw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[white,anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \else
            \draw[very thick] (0,\pgnbr) rectangle (\swidth-0.07cm,\pgnbr+1);
            \node[anchor=mid,font=\bfseries] at (\swidth/2,\pgnbr+0.5) {\number\numexpr\i-1};
        \fi
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%% TITLE

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\Large\bfseries}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\hspace{-\beamerleftmargin}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,\theight);
\node[anchor=mid] at (\paperwidth/2,\theight/2) {\insertframetitle};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

%%

\begin{document}

\setlength\sheight{\dimexpr(\paperheight-\theight)/(\inserttotalframenumber-1) \relax}

{
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}{First}
First
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second}
Second
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third}
Third
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This crashed sometimes. I had to set sheight within a condition `\ifnum\inserttotalframenumber > 1`. It requires two runs for whatever reason, but it's acceptable.